# Java: inheritance and arrays, and their children

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, extends

Java:
Simple question... why can I not use array[0].childMethod?

Notice that myList.method() works, but when stored in an array, method() becomes unusable.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle[] array = new Vehicle[1];

        Car myList = new Car();
        System.out.println( myList.myMethod() );    //Output: 1

        array[0] = myList;
        System.out.println( array[0].myMethod() );  //Doesn't work.

    }
}
class Vehicle{

}
class Car extends Vehicle{
    public int myMethod(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is myMethod() defined in Vehicle class?

Comment: Bad naming ; why would you ever call a car object myList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the vehicle class to an abstract class like so:

```
public abstract class vehicle{
```

And then make an abstract method in vehicle like so:

```
abstract int myMethod() ;
```

Then that should work nicely.

If you want to learn more, the YouTube channel thenewboston has some amazing java tutorials.

I highly recommend having a look. They helped me out so much.

Comment: While the other answers are correct, this ended up being the fix I needed, as my task is to create a Vehicle array and fill it with various children (Truck, car, etc). Thank you.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Notice `Vehicle` is your PARENT Class

```
 Vehicle[] array = new Vehicle[1];//instance of parent
```

`Car` is your inherited CHILD class

```
 Car myList = new Car();//instance of child
```

> Child can access Parent's methods and its own methods but not Vice versa. Parent can't access child's method unless you implement [Dynamic Method Dispatch/Runtime Polymorphism](http://www.studytonight.com/java/dynamic-method-dispatch) . (This is termed as Polymorphism in biology - one of the OOP pillars)

**Your `array`  is instance of parent** so it can't access myMethod of child. But `myList` is instance of car so it can access method `myMethod`

For that you will have to declare as

```
 Car[] array = new Car[1];
```

Or else you can simply `cast` like

```
 ((Car)array[0]).myMethod()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can simply cast the array item:

```
((Car) array[0]).myMethod()
```

As for question "why?" - compiler doesn't know if there is a Car object or any other Vehicle inheritor in the array.

Answer (score 2):

array[0] is super class reference.

mylist is a subclass object.

You are trying to call subclass's method from superclass reference variable.. it will only work  if the method in sub class is overridden.

Please read below concept..
Dyanamic method dispatch..

Any help is appreciated.

```
  public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Vehicle[] array = new Vehicle[1];

      Car myList = new Car();
      System.out.println( myList.myMethod() );    //Output: 1

      array[0] = myList;
      System.out.println( array[0].myMethod() );  // output 1
      }
   }
  class Vehicle{

      public int myMethod(){
        return 100;
       }
  }

  class Car extends Vehicle{

    @Override
    public int myMethod(){
     return 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice approach :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `myMethod` is defined in `Car` only. Since `array` is of type `Vehicle` it does not know about `myMethod`. This is saying - I am using all the elements in `array` as a `Vehicle`, the element  may have other methods or parameters but for the purpose of `array` I am focusing on the methods in `Vehicle` class.

A small work-around is to cast `array[0]` to `Car` i.e., `((Car)array[0]).myMethod()`.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile the code you will get *compile time error(not runtime error)*. The reason behind this is that:
the type of **array[0]** is *Vehicle* and then compiler thinks the type of **array[0]**  *Vehicle* and *myMethod()* method is not present in class *Vehicle*. So the error come up.

**note:** the compile dont know any runtime information.